# Cpanel list of users suddenly went empty

Tags: cpanel

I am new to Cpanel.  I have been logging into a Cpanel account and usually seeing list of users on the right-hand side under the "General Information" tab.  It's a drop down tab and I can select different domains that are hosted from the same server and IP through GoDaddy.  There are usually several accounts there that take me what seems to be separate volumes on the server where email addresses, settings, disk-usuage are all managed separately.

However, suddenly today, the list of users under the "Current User" drop-down are all gone.  There is only the main user account that I try to log in under.
[image]
How do I get that list of users back
Is there another way to select the user for the other domain in the Cpanel account?

Answer (score 0):

on left side you can see a "Settings" Icon , Press there .

Now select "Group Linkable Services" & View All from the list.

It will list all accounts

Comment: I cannot find the "Settings" icon.  Is it on the main page of Cpanel?  I added screenshot of the main page I'm looking at to the OP.